# With spring-data-elasticsearch and searching for similar documents, how to get similarity score?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using the latest version of elasticsearch (in docker) and a spring boot (latest version) app where I attempt to search for similar documents.  My document class has a String field:

```
@Field(
        name = "description",
        type = FieldType.Text,
        fielddata = true,
        analyzer = "icu_analyzer",
        termVector = TermVector.with_positions_offsets,
        similarity = Similarity.BM25)
private String description;
```

I get plenty of results for my query when I use the built-in `searchSimilar` method:

```
public Page<BookInfo> findSimilarDocuments(final long id) {
    return bookInfoRepository.findById(id)
            .map(bookInfo -> bookInfoRepository.searchSimilar(bookInfo, new String[]{"description"}, pageable))
            .orElse(Page.empty());
}
```

However, I have no idea how similar the documents are, because it is just a page of my Document object.  It would be great to be able to see the similarity score, or to set a similarity threshold when performing the query.  Is there something different that I should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a look, the existing method `Page<T> searchSimilar(T entity, @Nullable String[] fields, Pageable pageable)` was added to the `ElasticsearchRepository` interface back in 2013, it just returns a `Page<T>` which does not contain any score information.
Since Spring Data Elasticsearch version 4.0 the score information is available and when you look at the implementation you see that it is stripped from the return value of the function in order to adhere to the method signature from the interface:

```java
public Page<T> searchSimilar(T entity, @Nullable String[] fields, Pageable pageable) {

    Assert.notNull(entity, "Cannot search similar records for 'null'.");
    Assert.notNull(pageable, "'pageable' cannot be 'null'");

    MoreLikeThisQuery query = new MoreLikeThisQuery();
    query.setId(stringIdRepresentation(extractIdFromBean(entity)));
    query.setPageable(pageable);

    if (fields != null) {
        query.addFields(fields);
    }

    SearchHits<T> searchHits = execute(operations -> operations.search(query, entityClass, getIndexCoordinates()));
    SearchPage<T> searchPage = SearchHitSupport.searchPageFor(searchHits, pageable);
    return (Page<T>) SearchHitSupport.unwrapSearchHits(searchPage);
}
```

You could implement a custom repository fragment (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.6/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) that provides it's own implementation of the method that returns a `SearchPage<T>`:

```java
public SearchPage<T> searchSimilar(T entity, @Nullable String[] fields, Pageable pageable) {

    Assert.notNull(entity, "Cannot search similar records for 'null'.");
    Assert.notNull(pageable, "'pageable' cannot be 'null'");

    MoreLikeThisQuery query = new MoreLikeThisQuery();
    query.setId(stringIdRepresentation(extractIdFromBean(entity)));
    query.setPageable(pageable);

    if (fields != null) {
        query.addFields(fields);
    }

    SearchHits<T> searchHits = execute(operations -> operations.search(query, entityClass, getIndexCoordinates()));
    SearchPage<T> searchPage = SearchHitSupport.searchPageFor(searchHits, pageable);
    return searchPage;
}
```

A `SearchPage<T>` is a page containing `SearchHit<T>` instances; these contain the entity and the additional information like the score.

Comment: Thank you for this.  It was pretty close, although the scores in the search hits came back as "NaN".  I had to use a native query in order to make it work.

Comment: Strange. I was looking with the debugger at was is returned in the test code for this method, and there the score had values.